# How to reduce top menu bar height

Tags: css, html

I am trying to reduce the size of the **top bar menu**. 
But their is a only option I found that is **line-height**. 
I just set the height of the *top bar* class but it's not working. How can I make the header Height smaller??

**Web Site Url:**
http://starconsortiumbd.com/

**Html Code**

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="header-right-bar text-right">
    <ul class="contact-wrapper">
      <li class="acces">
        <ul>
          <li><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"></a><a href="#">info@starconsortiumbd.com</a></li>

        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <ul class="social-icon">
          <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/starconsortiumbd/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="https://linkedin.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="http://gmail.com/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- header-right-bar -->
</div>
</div>
<!-- top-bar -->
</div>
</div>
<!-- top-bar -->
```

Comment: show your code please

Comment: You can adjust the padding in the  .header-section .navbar  if position of logo can be adjusted. Other than that change line-height. Also change margin-top of logo to adjust

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: http://i.prntscr.com/d2M2xEbTQ0G4kEzYuxFQ0g.png This is what I get after reducing the `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` values to `11px` for `.header-section .top-bar .header-left-bar .contact-wrapper li` and `.header-section .top-bar .header-right-bar ul li`

Comment: Thank you very much Manoj Kumar. Now I got the point.

Comment: Nice, Rumana. Can you answer your own question and mark it please? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have navbar then try adding this in your css file:

```
.navbar-nav > li > a {
  padding-top:5px !important; padding-bottom:5px !important;
}
.navbar {
  min-height:32px !important
}
```

Else just change the "navbar" with your class name.

```
.yourclass-yourclass > li > a {
  padding-top:5px !important; padding-bottom:5px !important;
}
.yourclass {
  min-height:32px !important
}
```

If above code doesn't work then try below:

```
.navbar {
  padding-top: 0.25rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.25rem;
  font-size: smaller;
  line-height: 1em;
}
```